# Firestore Snapshot Read only last document

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

```
fire.firestore().collection('Customer').get()
  .then(data=>{
    data.docs.forEach(doc=>{
      let db = fire.firestore().collection(`Customer`)
      db.where("updated", ">=", 0).limit(100).onSnapshot(async doc=>{
        try {
          await doc.docs.map(each=>{
            setDatas([...datas, {...each.data()}])
          })
        }
      })
  })
```

I am trying to append the object in the array to query from firestore.
However, somehow it only reads last document.
Please help me if you could store state without using array.

Comment: What "object" you're attempting to append?

Comment: I want to append Object from ...each.data() to a state array

Answer (score 0):

Checking your code and running this [data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#example_data) as sample I could notice your code is getting all the results and not just the last one, so there could be something else. Also it seems like a double unnecessary query.

Instead you can query all the docs you may want to get them using `.. where("updated", ">=", 0).limit(100) ..` and not a query inside a query.

You can use the sample code from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) to make something more simpler:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
let db = admin.firestore();

const citiesRef = db.collection('Customer');
const snapshot = await citiesRef.where('updated', '>=', 100).limit(100).get();
if (snapshot.empty) {
console.log('No matching documents.');
return;
}  

snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    //Your code here to add to your array
});
```

This code is for `NodeJS` but you can adapt it to `ReactJS`